# Setting window opacity on Qt linuxfb plugin does not work

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I want to make a mask widget(top-level, means that window) with opacity 0.75 on linuxfb.

As it is a top-level widget(means that no parent).
I cannot use stylesheet "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,75%)".

I have tried:

```
MaskWidget::MaskWidget() {
   setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

1.

```
   setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
   this->setWindowOpacity(0.75); //show warning "This plugin does not support setting window opacity"
```

2.

```
   QRect desktopRect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(this);        
   setGeometry(0, 0, desktopRect.width(), desktopRect.height());
   setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); // it seems that not work
   QGraphicsOpacityEffect* oe = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
   oe->setOpacity(0.75);
   this->setGraphicsEffect(oe);
```

```
}
```

The above methods work well in ubuntu and windows, but in my device with QPA linuxfb not work.

Comment: The warning is there for a reason. LinuxFB QPA does not support window transparency. Can you try EGLFS instead?

Comment: For reasons that remain unclear, EGLFS can not display, so I can only use LinxuFB.